# CSS: After the transition, the words tremble a little bit

Tags: html, css, sass

I deployed [this](https://dreamy-bell-5aed9b.netlify.app/#tours) tutorial project on Netlify. As I hover over those three cards, I see that the words move a little down or up. There is a problem with **Chrome**, not Firefox.

I use `transition: all 0.3s ease` and `transform: rotateY(180deg)` to rotate cards 180 degrees. It often solves this problem for me to use `backface-visibility:hidden`, but it doesn't in this case.
[This](https://github.com/elmi-elmi/demo-CSS-Natours/blob/master/sass/components/_card.scss) is the link to my github if you want to see my code. See lines **14** and **53** in SASS code.

Please tell me what the source of the problem is and how you would solve it in general.

Comment: "Since I don't expect you to check my code" ... that's exactly what stackoverflow is for. Please post the code that gives you problems :)

Comment: @Kokodoko :))) Thank you. If you check again, I linked my github link. " This is the link to my github if you want to see my code. See lines 14 and 53 in SASS code."

Comment: Yes, but to ask a question on Stackoverflow, the question itself needs to contain the problematic code, see also : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask